# Chromedriver driver.get() working on Mac but does work on Windows (Chrome version 101.0.4951.54)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing a program that uses selenium and chromedriver to load a page. The same code loads the page (nytimes.com) on my Windows computer but not on my Mac. On my Mac, it loads the webdriver with the blank data:, page but just stops and the console log just shows it waiting. I don't know why the driver does not get the page.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

opts = Options()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get('http://nytimes.com')

html = driver.page_source
```

This below is the last thing it shows in the console log. It just waits there after that with the blinking cursor.

```
====== WebDriver manager ======
Current google-chrome version is 101.0.4951
Get LATEST chromedriver version for 101.0.4951 google-chrome
Driver [/Users/me/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac64_m1/101.0.4951.41/chromedriver] 
found in cache
testing.py:14: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass 
in a Service object
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

What could be the problem? I have a suspicion that it's the new version of chrome that I'm using but why would that change anything?

Answer (score 0):

From the below message it seems you executed code before which installed older version of driver. Now when you trying to run code again , it detecting older version
in cache. Please check below path once.

Driver [/Users/me/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac64_m1/101.0.4951.41/chromedriver]
found in cache